# Repsonsive divs with background / text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I need to setup multiple divs, one under another that have both a responsive background image with text over top.  Right now I have the following setup:

http://secretsofpoolecreekvillage.com/index_temp.php

.. which worked fine when there was only the one div ".bg1".  As soon as I add another div under it, they overlap.  I'm assuming this has to do with the position: absolute; on each of these divs.  I don't know how to accomplish this otherwise though.

```
.bg1 {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.bg1 img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.bg1 h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:'ITCFranklinGothicStd-Book';
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.bg1 h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:'TimesEuropaLTStd-Bold';
    font-size: 62px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 50px;

}

.bgContent1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

<div class="bg1">
<img src="/images/bg_1.jpg">
<div class="bgContent1">
    <h1>SECRETS OF</h1>
    <h2>POOLE CREEK VILLAGE</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just set a background to `.bg1`? Like `.bg1 { background: url('images/bg_1.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center; background-size: 100% 100%; }`

Comment: How would I get the height of the div to automatically change based on browser size?  If I do that it seems I have to set a height for it.

Comment: Since you have absolute position set on the div, just do `.bg1 { ... top: 0; right:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }`

Comment: Does the text need to be dynamic? If not, photoshop the text in lol